# How to make anchor links in newsletters work in iOS 8 mail app

Tags: ios, iphone, email, ios8

I have a newsletter that works fine for every email client we have already tested, and it was working fine on iPhone mail app until Apple released iOS 8.

The external links in the newsletter are still working, but the TOC links to the sections in the newsletter stopped working on the Mail app from iOS 8

Can anyone help me with this?

I'm not even sure how to ask apple for help or file a bug there.

Answer (score 2):

Anchor links have been disabled as of IOS 8!